# How do I return models related to a related model?

Tags: cakephp

I have 3 models.

`Webcast` and `Tag` are associated witha HABTMA association.

`Webcast` and `Host` are associated with a hasMany relationship (`Webcast` has many `Host`).

When I do a `Tag->find` I get `Tag` and `Webcast` models, however I want to get all 3. How can I go about that?

Comment: **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query is using $this->webcast->find then you'll get everything your looking for, except you can't search 'TAG' without joining the tables before the query.  If you want to search 'TAG' which I recommend in this situation then your need to go into your Tag model and create relationships there too.

Tag HABTM Webcast

should do it.  If you're not getting host then try 'recursive' => 2 in your query.

```
$this->Tag->find('all');
```

OR

```
$this->Tag->find('all', array('recursive' => 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

From docs

> The recursive property defines how deep CakePHP should go to fetch associated model data via find(), and read() methods.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive